# How to add content to dynamic nested JSON with Perl script

Tags: json, perl, loops, multidimensional-array

Hi I have to add some new array of content to existing JSON array dynamically. I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "deal": {
    "distributionWindows": [
      {
        "availableAt": "2016-10-08T23:00:00Z",
        "availableUntil": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
        "constraints": [
          {
            "categoryIds": [
              "1760gh81-5m83-4b16-a2c5-6ed511f35d9a",
              "09f78fg9-2728-4nl1-a601-c5176744d534"
            ],
            "enforcedAt": "2016-10-08T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedUntil": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
            "type": "forbidden"
          }
        ],
        "enabled": false,
        "type": "prefeature"
      },
      {
        "availableAt": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
        "availableUntil": "2016-12-12T21:44:23Z",
        "constraints": [
          {
            "categoryIds": [
              "1324kj81-5e89-4b16-a1u5-6uy511f35d9a",
              "1234nhgt-2728-4ac1-a601-c5176744d534"
            ],
            "enforcedAt": "2016-11-09T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedUntil": "2016-12-12T22:59:59Z",
            "type": "forbidden"
          }
        ],
        "enabled": false,
        "type": "featured"
      }
    ],
    "inviteOnly": true,
    "wowDeal": true
  }
}
```

For this JSON I have to add new content for every constraints and finally JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "deal": {
    "distributionWindows": [
      {
        "availableAt": "2016-10-08T23:00:00Z",
        "availableUntil": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
        "constraints": [
          {
            "categoryIds": [
              "1760gh81-5m83-4b16-a2c5-6ed511f35d9a",
              "09f78fg9-2728-4nl1-a601-c5176744d534"
            ],
            "enforcedAt": "2016-10-08T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedUntil": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
            "type": "forbidden"
          },
          {
            "categoryIds": [
              “9fiu8908-7d78-22e4-a228-7403453512e8"
            ],
            "enforcedAt": "2016-10-08T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedUntil": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
            "type": "allowed"
          }
        ],
        "enabled": false,
        "type": "prefeature"
      },
      {
        "availableAt": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
        "availableUntil": "2016-12-12T21:44:23Z",
        "constraints": [
          {
            "categoryIds": [
              "1324kj81-5e89-4b16-a1u5-6uy511f35d9a",
              "1234nhgt-2728-4ac1-a601-c5176744d534"
            ],
            "enforcedAt": "2016-11-09T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedUntil": "2016-12-12T22:59:59Z",
            "type": "forbidden"
          },
          {
            "categoryIds": [
              “9fiu8908-7d78-22e4-a228-7403453512e8"
            ],
            "enforcedAt": "2016-10-08T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedUntil": "2016-10-09T23:00:00Z",
            "type": "allowed"
          }
        ],
        "enabled": false,
        "type": "featured"
      }
    ],
    "inviteOnly": true,
    "wowDeal": true
  }
}
```

How to do this using perl? How do I loop dynamically and add the last constraint? I can extract values but I am not sure how to loop it the JSON array and add content in middle. And main problem is it is dynamic, some times it may have one constraint array in existing JSON, and some times it may have 2 or 3. But I have to add my new constraint at the end of the every distributionWindow.

Comment: Can you please show the work you have done to solve it ??

Comment: @AkhileshAwasthi                                                                                                 my $json_array = decode_json($json);

 foreach my $item($json_array) {

        print $item->{deal}->{distributionWindows}[0]{constraints}[0]{categoryIds}[0];

        print "\n";

        print $item->{deal}->{distributionWindows}[0]{constraints}[0]{categoryIds}[1];

        print "\n";

        print print $item->{deal}->{distributionWindows}[0]{constraints};

 } I am new to this perl and do not know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
sub process_window($)
{
   my($window) = @_;
   my $constraints = $window->{constraints};

   my $new_constraint;
   # your code that decides if constraint needs to be added goes here...

   # update constraints in window
   push(@{ $constraints }, $new_constraint);
}

my $data = decode_json($json);
foreach my $distWindow (@{ $data->{deal}->{DistributionWindows} }) {
    process_window($distWindow);
}
my $new_json = encode_json($data);
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan. It is working for inserting into the array. But for entire new content extra double quote is getting added and also a backslash for content. Added content is like this: 
         constraints": [
          {
            "type": "forbidden",
            "categoryIds": [
              "1560ef81-5e83-4b16-a1d5-6de511f35d9a",
              "09d96db9-2728-4ac1-a601-c5176744d534"
            ],
            "enforcedUntil": "2017-11-09T23:00:00Z",
            "enforcedAt": "2017-11-08T23:00:00Z"
          }, "{\"categoryIds\": [\"0c5401a4-7d96-44f8-a229-7403453512e8\"]}"

Comment: @Nagesh that can only mean that your strings contain `"` (quotes) themselves. Please compare

`perl -MJSON -e '$k = "test"; $d{$k}++; print encode_json(\%d), "\n";'` -> `{"test":1}`

vs.

`perl -MJSON -e '$k = "\"test\""; $d{$k}++; print encode_json(\%d), "\n";'` -> `{"\"test\"":1}`

Comment: @Nagesh if the strings that get converted to hash keys are passed in, then I would check and add a quote stripper, e.g. maybe this simple one is already good enough for your use case: `$key =~ s/"//g;`